# v-if with two conditions

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code where v-if is always showing true even when `doc.acceptance_letter = ''`

```
<a 
  target="_blank"
  class="has-text-link"
  v-if="doc.acceptance_letter!=null || doc.acceptance_letter!= '' "
  :href="doc.acceptance_letter"  
>
  view
</a>
```

I want hide this anchor tag when `doc.acceptance_letter` is null or empty.
Could anyone advise what I did wrong?

Comment: you can try `v-if="doc.acceptance_letter"`

Comment: @BTL Thank you. This is so simple and yet I could not come up with your solution.

Comment: Your code didn't also work because if the string is '' then it's not null, which makes the first condition true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will always show, because it will always be different from `null` or `''` (a variable can't have two values simultaneously). As suggested on comments, you can just check `v-if="doc.acceptance_letter` that will hide it in any falsy value, or do a `v-if="doc.acceptance_letter != null && doc.acceptance_letter != ''`

```
<a 
  target="_blank"
  class="has-text-link"
  v-if="doc.acceptance_letter
  :href="doc.acceptance_letter"  
>
  view
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use && instead of ||, to display the tag whendoc.acceptance_letter is not null and not empty.

```
<a 
  target="_blank"
  class="has-text-link"
  v-if="doc.acceptance_letter!=null && doc.acceptance_letter!= '' "
  :href="doc.acceptance_letter">
  view
</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Missing a '='

```
v-if="doc.acceptance_letter!== null || doc.acceptance_letter!== '' "
```